# Bootstrap: Navbar: nav-side-menu: collapse on small screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a nav-side-menu in my html page that shows up fixed top and fixed left. What I am trying to do is get it to collapse to the left side and show a button with 3 bars when viewed on small screens(I don't want it to disappear). For example, the way the sidebar collapses when the window is made smaller: https://pro.propeller.in/components/sidebar.php. This is how far I got:

```css
  .nav-side-menu {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    background-color: #2e353d;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    /*width: 300px;*/
    width: 210px;
    height: 100% !important; /*this line made sure when the screen is maximized, the side menu's height is restored*/
    color: #033c73;   
    }

    .nav-side-menu .brand {
        background-color: #23282e;
        line-height: 50px;
        display: block;        
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
        /*display: none;*/
    }

    .nav-side-menu ul,
    .nav-side-menu li {
        list-style: none;
        /*padding: 0px;*/
        margin: 0px;
        line-height: 15px;
        /*line-height: 10px;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-left: 10px;
       
    }

        .nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
        .nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            content: "\f078";
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            float: right;
        }

        .nav-side-menu ul .active,
        .nav-side-menu li .active {
            border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
            background-color: #4f5b69;
        }

        .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
        .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
            color: #d19b3d;
        }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
                color: #d19b3d;
            }

        .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
        .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
            background-color: #181c20;
            border: none;
            line-height: 28px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
                background-color: #020203;
            }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                content: "\f105";
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

    .nav-side-menu li {
        /*JS: edited*/
        /*padding-left: 0px;*/
        padding-left: 10px;
        border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
    }

        .nav-side-menu li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            /*color: #e1ffff;*/
            color: white;
        }

            .nav-side-menu li a i {
                padding-left: 10px;
                width: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
            }

    .nav-side-menu li a:hover {
    color: red;
    }
        
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-side-menu {
        /*position: relative;*/
        /*position: absolute;*/
        /*width: 100%;*/
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        z-index: 10 !important; /* for overlay */
        display: none;  /* this hides the menu when the screen is made smaller */
    }

        .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            z-index: 10 !important;
            padding: 3px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            color: #000;
            width: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }

    .brand {
        text-align: left !important;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        line-height: 50px !important;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 767px) {
        .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<nav class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div>

      

           <div class="nav-side-menu sticky-top" style="padding-top: 100px">
                                   <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav">-->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                  <li>
                                                   
                    <a href="" class="nav-link expanded" data-toggle="collapse" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#2e353d;cursor:default">
                                                       Profile&nbsp;
                                                       <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
                     </a>
                  <!--<ul class="dropdown-menu">-->
                  <ul class="flex-column nav">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                                                                   
                          <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Profile/Item1">Item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                         <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Profile/Item2">Item 2</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item">
                          <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Profile/Item3">Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Profile/Item4">Item 4</a>
                        </li>
                                                               
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Profile/Item5">Item 5</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
             </ul>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li>
                 <a href="" class="nav-link expanded" data-toggle="collapse" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#2e353d;cursor:default">
                                                       Options&nbsp;
                 </a>
            <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Options/Item6">Item 6</a>
                </li>
                                                                       
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Options/Item7">Item 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="" class="nav-link expanded" data-toggle="collapse" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:white;background-color:#2e353d;cursor:default">
                                                       Reports&nbsp;
                 </a>
                 <ul class="flex-column nav">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                          <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Report/Item8">Item 8</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item">
                            <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Report/Item9">Item 9</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item">
                            <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Report/Item10">Item 10</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:15px;" class="nav-link" href="Report/Item11">Item 11</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
            </ul>
                                   
        </div>
    <div class="navbar-header" style="padding-top: 0px">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-side-menu">
               <span class="icon-bar">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
           </div>
   </div>
</nav>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Edit: I am now able to hide and show the side menu on resizing the window. And also show the toggle button hide and display in smaller screens.
But, when the menu is toggled(hidden) in smaller screen and the window is resized, how do I make the menu appear again?

Comment: you can check the link :  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My code already has a "Toggle Navigation" button that does the job of toggling the menu. What I am looking for is for the menu to automatically slide and collapse into a 3 bar button on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Bootstrap 4, it has such an inbuilt class to already do it. Look at [Bootstrap Navbar Responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)
It is preferable and it automatically is responsive for every screen from mobiles to desktops and many more. So please have a read at it.

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting css styles, I was able to hide and show the menu on smaller screens. Please see comments on the original post.